# updating service error (Google Cloud - Flask App)

Tags: python, flask, gcloud

I am trying to Deploy my Flask application on Google Cloud but getting an error

╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [3] The following errors occurred while copying files to App Engine:
File https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.content-based-recommendations.appspot.com/d248249521544673e03be52ee573ecc4ba94c3ae failed with: Failed to copy file.

Details: [                                                                                                                [
    {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ResourceInfo",
      "description": "Failed to copy file.",
      "resourceName": "https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.content-based-recommendations.appspot.com/d248249521544673e03be52ee573ecc4ba94c3ae",
      "resourceType": "file"
    }                                                                                                                     ]
]

I have tried to delete the resource from bucket and redeploy but found same error.

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per error, it seems that user don't  have permission to access bucket from which you are trying to deploy.
Please make sure that user account has sufficient permission to write in bucket.

Comment: can you please tell me how to give permission to user account ?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions, please follow this documentation

Comment: Same error again , after giving all the permissions